# How to overwrite fields when you COPY FROM data?

Tags: cassandra, copy, cql, cqlsh, import-from-csv

Is it possible to somehow **overwrite** existing counters-fields when COPY FROM data (from CSV),
or **completely delete** rows from the database?

When I `COPY FROM` data to existing rows, the counters are summarized.

I can’t completely `DELETE` these rows as well:
although it seems that the rows are deleted, when you re-`COPY FROM` the data from CSV,
the counters-fields continue to increase.

Comment: What is the table structure? are these fields counters?

Comment: @AlexOtt Yes, that's right, they are counters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set counters to the specific value - for them the only supported operation is either increase, or decrease.  To set them to specific value you need either to decrease it to its current value, and then increase to desired value, but this will require that you read value. Or you need to delete corresponding cells (or whole row), and perform increase operation using desired number.

The second approach could be implemented easier, but will require that you first generate a file with CQL DELETE commands based on the content of your CSV file, and then use `COPY FROM` - if nobody increased values since deletion, then counters will get correct values.

Comment: The problem is that the second one does not work for some reason in my case (the counters are not reset even after deleting the row). Is this not standard behavior for Cassandra?

Comment: maybe version dependent? What version are you using? Works for me: https://gist.github.com/alexott/a8e7d89318915caa3bc455d77a52ab32